# Android Studio: Could not find any version that matches com.google.gms:play-services:6.1.+

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

I've recently updated my android studio and when I try to sync my gradle file I get the below error:

```
Could not find any version that matches com.google.gms:play-services:6.1.+
```

I understand that Android Studio ships with it's own sdk so I've installed the ADT sdk and pointed my project to this but I still get the same error, here are my gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.4.2.jar')
    compile project(':ws_wrapper')
    compile project(':custom_slider_library')
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+'
    compile project(':shinobicharts-android-library')
    compile files('libs/shinobicharts-android-trial-1.3.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/androidplot-core-0.6.1-SNAPSHOT.jar')
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
    compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    compile files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
}
```

I'm unsure as to what to do next, my sdk manager is up to date, does anyone have any ideas?  I can't run this at the moment due to this issue.
If I try to add a dependency via the project structure the google play services isn't available on the maven drop down list.

Just to add this line `@integer/google_play_services_version` in the manifest is also causing an issue it says cannot resolve symbol

Answer (score 6):

Your SDK isn't actually up-to-date. You need to install revision 12 of the Google Repository; that's the one that ships Google Play Services 6.1.11.

Comment: I am having the same problem and have confirmed I have revision 12 of the Google Repository, as well as revision 20 of Google Play services

Comment: @MeanderingCode have you fixed your problem? i have same problem.

Comment: In these cases you may want to post a new question and include your exact error messages and what you've got in your Gradle scripts.

Comment: @savepopulation I have.  In my case I needed to add an extra `maven{}` block in my `repositories{}` block with the path to the google specific local maven repository in my `build.gradle` file. (A more detailed outline is not appropriate for a comment)

Comment: @MeanderingCode That sounds strange. I think there must be something messed up about your configuration, because you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @MeanderingCode thanks for your help. i fixed it too. i changed my targetSdkVersion 21 from 20 and i changed my dependencies compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11' you need jdk7 and if you are using mac and android studio you have to change your path.

Comment: @ScottBarta I thought so, too. I will be digging into this realm more extensively when I get the cycles to implement continuous integration for my project, but that won't be very soon.